# WordPress - Redirect logged in users from login page to custom page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a page template that will be used to show a custom wordpress login form.

```php
<?php 
/*
* Template Name: Login
*/

get_header();
if( !is_user_logged_in() ){
?>

html code 
<?php 
} else {
  $user = wp_get_current_user();
  if( current_user_can('edit_users') && in_array('customrole', $user->roles) ){
   wp_redirect( site_url('/role-page') );
   exit;
  }
  if( current_user_can('edit_users') && in_array('customrole1', $user->roles) ){
   wp_redirect( site_url('/role-page1') );
   exit;
  }
}
get_footer();
?>
```

I've noticed that if an user is logged in, the page will be loaded and is blank, the users will be not redirected to the desired location. How I can fix this problem and let the logged users be redirected based on their role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use template_redirect

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {

if ( is_user_logged_in()){

$restricted = array( 250(login page id) ); // all your restricted pages

if ( in_array( get_queried_object_id(), $restricted ) ) {
     wp_redirect( site_url( '/custom_page slug' ) ); 
     exit();
  }
 }
});
```

Comment: will this be possible from the page code or I need to add it in function? I just need that the users will not see a blank page but are redirected to their assigned page

Comment: Add this is functions.php file

Comment: but this will be only redirect all users to a page, also I want to avoid adding actions in my functions file, I already have a custom plugin that is managing a lot of things I need

Answer (score 1):

I think we can use wp_redirect before content is sent to the browser. You should use hooks for that.

But you can try this for custom template:

```
global $current_user;
$role         = $current_user->roles;
$current_role = implode( $role );
if ( $current_role == 'customrole' ) {
    $url = site_url( '/role-page' );
    echo "<script>window.location.href = '$url';</script>";
    exit;
}
```